# CentOS Traffic Filter

Tags: centos, iptables, routing, proxy, squid

I am trying to use Squid to filter the traffic flowing through the network. I am also trying to make this system transparent. My network setup is like so:

```
Router -> CentOS Machine -> The rest of the network.
Router: 192.168.1.254
CentOS: 192.168.1.104
LAN   : 192.168.1.0/24 and 81.150.192.224/28
```

I need all network to be passed to the router - unmodified - and then have it pass the response to Squid. The issues I've encountered so far are DNS - as in I'm unable to get the traffic sent to the machine because it is unable to look it up - issues with having two different subnets(one for my LAN and one for my Public IP's.).

How would I get this to function ?

Comment: So the clients' default gateway should be the router and their HTTP proxy should point to the CentOS box.  Squid doesn't work for every protocol, only [HTTP, FTP, and gopher](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/AboutSquid)

Comment: That's all I need. And then just let the other traffic pass through unfiltered.

Answer (score 1):

The clients' default gateway should be the router and their HTTP proxy should point to the CentOS box.

[Squid's site](http://www.squid-cache.org/) has a ton of documentation, including [example configurations](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples), a thorough [FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq0) and a very comprehensive guide for [configuring browsers](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringBrowsers).

In regards to a transparent proxy, and an example configuration can be found [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/FullyTransparentWithTPROXY?highlight=%28ConfigExamples%2FIntercept%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FAuthenticate%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FChat%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FStreams%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FReverse%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FStrange%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FExtreme%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FPortal%29%7C%28ConfigExamples%2FSmp%29) and current TPROXY documentation can be found [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4)

Comment: I am trying to make a transparent proxy. I am aware Squid only supports certain protocols and that's why I'd like to route things like HTTP and FTP to Squid and just let the rest pass to the router and then return the response from the router to the originating requester.

Comment: I've added some more links to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the added links. Using the links you've provided, I was able to set up the iptables to route all the traffic correctly and it's not working perfectly. I'll post my answer and mark it the answer as soon as I can. But thanks for the links, they were the key to me solving this problem.

Comment: Good to hear.  If you think the links will help others with the same problem you can upvote the answer.